# openvpn not redirecting, issue on client side

Tags: vpn, openvpn, redirect

I have a openvpn server. The configuration with gateway redirection works on my mobile phone but not on my linux computer. This means that the ip on my mobile phone changes but not in my computer. This is my .ovpn file (same on mobile and computer):

```
client                                                                                                                                                                                                               
dev tun                                                                                                                                                                                                              
proto udp4                                                                                                                                                                                                            
sndbuf 0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
rcvbuf 0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
mssfix 1200                                                                                                                                                                                                          
tun-mtu 1200                                                                                                                                                                                                         
remote ip_server port                                                                                                                                                                                            
resolv-retry infinite                                                                                                                                                                                                
nobind                                                                                                                                                                                                               
persist-key                                                                                                                                                                                                          
persist-tun                                                                                                                                                                                                          
remote-cert-tls server                                                                                                                                                                                               
auth SHA512                                                                                                                                                                                                          
cipher AES-256-CBC                                                                                                                                                                                                   
comp-lzo                                                                                                                                                                                                             
setenv opt block-outside-dns                                                                                                                                                                                         
key-direction 1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
verb 3                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<ca>  
....
```

On the server side the important part of the configuration is the following:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

I have also set the configurations for postrouting in the ip tables on the server:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Finally, the results of `ip route  show table all` once connected to the vpn are the following:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
ip_server via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp2s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-5a527ab22980 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.29.0.0/16 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.178 metric 600 
broadcast 10.8.0.0 dev tun0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
local 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.8.0.2 
broadcast 10.8.0.255 dev tun0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.0.0 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.17.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
broadcast 172.18.0.0 dev br-5a527ab22980 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
local 172.18.0.1 dev br-5a527ab22980 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.18.0.1 
broadcast 172.18.255.255 dev br-5a527ab22980 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
broadcast 172.29.0.0 dev docker_gwbridge table local proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
local 172.29.0.1 dev docker_gwbridge table local proto kernel scope host src 172.29.0.1 
broadcast 172.29.255.255 dev docker_gwbridge table local proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
broadcast 192.168.43.0 dev wlp2s0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.178 
local 192.168.43.178 dev wlp2s0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.43.178 
broadcast 192.168.43.255 dev wlp2s0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.178 
2a04:cec0:118c:56c5::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::5a20:59ff:fed7:ea52 dev wlp2s0 proto ra metric 600 pref high
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a04:cec0:118c:56c5:b871:ba8b:2c0:2e7d dev wlp2s0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::a68d:6eb6:9fbd:ae6d dev wlp2s0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev wlp2s0 table local metric 256 pref medium
```

Comment: Exactly what is not working?

Comment: the gateway redirection, my ip is still the same once i connect to the vpn, however I have the redirect-gateway option activated

Comment: With the routing table you show here, I would expect you to have no connectivity at all to anywhere when the VPN is up. Are you sure you have posted this accurately? Please check with `ip route show table all`.

Comment: I updated the question. I was cropping a bit result of `ip route` for space, but know I put the complete result of ip route. There are some stuff coming from docker and some other things

Comment: Hm, OK, I still see the same thing. The problem I'm seeing is that there needs to be a route from your machine to the OpenVPN server's IP itself, that goes over your existing network connection, to carry the VPN tunnel itself. I can't find that route entry anywhere in there. So either you cropped it out (please do not do this, it's just confusing) or OpenVPN is not adding it. If the latter, I suggest reading OpenVPN's logs for when it makes a connection, very carefully.

Comment: I didn't crop anything this time for completeness this time =). Isn't the first route what you're talking about? if I ping the vpn server `10.8.0.1`  I get a response.

Comment: Well, that in itself is a real mystery. By chance are you connecting to your OpenVPN server via IPv6 (and forgot to mention it)?

Comment: Sorry but if I did I don't know how. With your comment I searched and I used `proto udp4` to force ipv4 on the client side and it's not connecting now. It's weird then, my phone uses ipv4 it works fine, and when I configure in my computer it doesn't.

Comment: I retried, it connected to the vpn with `proto udp4` now. However still the same problem. I updated the question. With the complete `ip route  show table all` and I added `upd4` to the configuration.

Comment: Is 77.206.139.161 the VPN server address? That's the route I was expecting to see, and now your routes are in a state where I expect everything to work. Time to have another look at the logs, this time both on client and server side.

Comment: yes it is, and damn... I forgot to obfuscate the ip :/, do you mind obfuscating it also?. Thanks for the help. It's pretty weird, with `udp4` it takes more time to connect. However I'll check out what can I see from the logs. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about obfuscating the IP. Obfuscation is pretty useless. Malicious actors try every IPv4 address anyway.

Comment: I still have some questions: 1) Once I modified `udp4` usually I get several messages `SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)` and takes a long time to connect. 2) I've been running in circles trying to use the logs to try to get the correct ip, how still don't know how. I suspect that it's due to the second line of the routes `default via 192.168.43.1` but I'm not sure how to change it with the ovpn file.